# Ionic Application White Screen and crash on mobile

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

ionic app crash when open app in device and emulators.
It Works fine in browsers!

```
>      vendor-es2015.js:7773 Uncaught TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
>     at newTrustedFunctionForJIT (vendor-es2015.js:7773)
>     at JitEvaluator.evaluateCode (vendor-es2015.js:7837)
>     at JitEvaluator.evaluateStatements (vendor-es2015.js:7811)
>     at CompilerFacadeImpl.jitExpression (vendor-es2015.js:21205)
>     at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileNgModule (vendor-es2015.js:21135)
>     at Function.get (vendor-es2015.js:94017)
>     at getNgModuleDef (vendor-es2015.js:68158)
>     at assertNgModuleType (vendor-es2015.js:68337)
>     at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (vendor-es2015.js:96051)
>     at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (vendor-es2015.js:96298)
```

When i use `ionic info` I got

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
> (C:\Users\pritesh.b\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)    Ionic
> Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.3
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4    @angular-devkit/schematics
> : 10.0.8    @angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.6    @capacitor/core : 2.4.6
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0    Cordova Platforms : none    Cordova
> Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)
>
> cordova-res : 0.15.3    native-run  : 1.3.0
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
> 6.14.11    OS     : Windows 10

Comment: Can you provide more info? Run `ionic info`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Angular 11? Try downgrading to Angular 8.

Comment: @johnborges @alex87 thanks! check this `ionic info`

Comment: What command are you using to open the app on device? From the info posted, it looks like you don't have a platform added yet.

Comment: @johnborges ionic capacitor run android

Comment: Try this first: `npx cap add android`